# How to add data markers inside a task bar gantt chart in syncfusion

Tags: javascript, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a gantt chart using syncfusion javascript. I am trying to add a data marker inside a task bar if the date of the marker falls within that date range as follows:

```
                TaskID: 1,
                TaskName: 'Project Initiation',
                StartDate: new Date('04/02/2019'),
                EndDate: new Date('05/21/2019'),
                    Indicators: [
                        {
                            'date': '04/10/2019',
                            'name': 'Design Phase',
                            'tooltip': 'Scheduled checkin',
                            'iconClass': 'okIcon e-icons'
                        }],
                TaskColor:'purple'
```

as you can see its the o4/10/2019 which falls with in the start and end date. But the indicator never shows up inside the taskbar its always getting hidden behind looking like this

[image: notworking]

but i want it to look like this

[image: how it should be]

reference :[syncfusion data markers](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/gantt/data-markers/)

Answer (score 0):

Taskbar has higher priority compared to indicator because taskbar is movable. Setting the z-indicator to the indicator span can move the indicator to above the taskbar.

```
<style>
  .e-gantt .e-gantt-chart .e-indicator-span {
    z-index: 3;
  }
</style>
```

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/sakfgm?file=data-source.ts,index.ts,index.html